# What is the equivalent of current_kernel_time in Linux kernel v5?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I tried to compile some kernel modules from Pleora eBUS SDK on a Linux Ubuntu 19.04 machine with Kernel version 5.0.0-38-generic, but got the compilation error:

```
error: implicit declaration of function ‘current_kernel_time’; did you mean ‘core_kernel_text’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  lTime = current_kernel_time();
```

and another (same issue) for function `do_gettimeofday`.

I noticed that `current_kernel_time` and `current_kernel_time64` were still available in kernel v4.15 (used by my other machine with Ubuntu 18.04 for example), last seen in [linux v4.19.97](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.97/source/include/linux/timekeeping32.h#L23). In [time.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0/source/include/linux/time.h) header of my kernel version there is a function `get_timespec64` which seems to do something similar, however it accepts 2 arguments and it doesn't seem correct to me (because in the sources I saw that there is a `copy_from_user` invoked) to pass some uninitialized `const struct __kernel_timespec __user *uts` as a second argument. Can someone give me some hint how to replace calls to `current_kernel_time` in my newer kernel version?

Example code that needs to be modified:

```
OS_UINT64 OS_TimeGetUS( OS_VOID )
{
    struct timespec64 lTime;
    lTime = current_kernel_time();
    return ( lTime.tv_sec * 1000000 + OS_DIV64( lTime.tv_nsec, 1000 ) );
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `current_kernel_time()` function got deprecated and moved to [`timekeeping32.h`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15/source/include/linux/timekeeping32.h#L15) in v4.15 ([commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=5dbf20127f8cca8588ad0b0e3e8ded587ac7afa0)) and then completely removed in v4.20 ([commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=976516404ff3fab2a8caa8bd6f5efc1437fed0b8)). Newer timekeeping functions were introduced in v4.18 ([commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=fb7fcc96a86cfaef0f6dcc0665516aa68611e736)).

The new exported functions are ([source](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0/source/include/linux/timekeeping.h#L41)):

```
extern void ktime_get_raw_ts64(struct timespec64 *ts);
extern void ktime_get_ts64(struct timespec64 *ts);
extern void ktime_get_real_ts64(struct timespec64 *tv);
extern void ktime_get_coarse_ts64(struct timespec64 *ts);
extern void ktime_get_coarse_real_ts64(struct timespec64 *ts);
```

See also [the relevant kernel documentation page](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.4/core-api/timekeeping.html), which states:

> ### Deprecated time interfaces
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> struct timespec current_kernel_time(void)
> struct timespec64 current_kernel_time64(void)
> struct timespec get_monotonic_coarse(void)
> struct timespec64 get_monotonic_coarse64(void)
> ```
>
> These are replaced by `ktime_get_coarse_real_ts64()` and `ktime_get_coarse_ts64()`. However, A lot of code that wants coarse-grained times can use the simple ‘jiffies’ instead, while some drivers may actually want the higher resolution accessors these days.

---

You can rewrite your code as:

```
OS_UINT64 OS_TimeGetUS( OS_VOID )
{
    struct timespec64 lTime;
    ktime_get_coarse_real_ts64(&lTime);
    return (lTime.tv_sec * 1000000 + OS_DIV64( lTime.tv_nsec, 1000 ) );
}
```

However I see that you are returning the time in microseconds. In such case, you might want to directly use [`ktime_t ktime_get(void)`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/timekeeping.html#c.ktime_get) or the equivalent [`u64 ktime_get_ns(void)`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/timekeeping.html#c.ktime_get_ns). The code snippet you provide could then be rewritten as:

```
OS_UINT64 OS_TimeGetUS( OS_VOID )
{
    return OS_DIV64(ktime_get_ns(), 1000);
}
```